# OData feeds are broken (again) on data.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

There are a few things I'd like to be able to query that I can't get (or get efficiently) via the SE API.  I'm considering building an app that consumes the OData feeds from Data Explorer, but the feeds are currently returning (500-class?) errors:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom

> The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

I am, however, relatively new to the OData interface, so it's possible I'm "doing it wrong" (tm)

Can I get support/status on this?

Comment: OData questions tend to end up here on meta, although it's arguable that this could be an appropriate topic for stackapps. Posting here to follow the current convention...

Comment: deployed Tim's fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL isn't a fan of double equal signs, so I [removed the extra one](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=b35d52c94c769d16fbf0b83000dd7dc8b5e3e2d9) to make the OData endpoint happy again. I'm not terribly familiar with the ins and outs of OData to verify that everything else is working correctly, but resolving the SQL error suggests that was the only issue.

Comment: Still getting the same error, although you guys might still be working (or this might not have been pushed to the live servers yet)

Comment: Yeah, this is just a change to my local copy. It'll be up to waffles if he wants to pull and deploy the change, but I'm sure he's sleeping now.

Comment: You mean I have to wait for something!?  On the INTERNET?  GAH.  I'm complaining to the President of the Internet about this.

Comment: Wait, and wait patiently. AND YOU'LL LIKE IT! Or, you know, go play games instead.